# save html form to xml with php childNodes->length error

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to save an HTML form and extra text to XML with PHP, but I have a problem.

I want to set to any data child an auto-id with the parameters childNodes->length.

This is ok, but when I try to have preserveWhiteSpace = false then the first two data have the same id=1.

With preserveWhiteSpace = false I have a right id, but I have not a nice format in my file.xml.

Here the code:
1. Html/Php

```
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) {
 $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","utf-8");
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $dom->formatOutput = true;
 $dom->load("a.xml");

 $rootElement = $dom->getElementsByTagName("document")->item(0);

 $total = $rootElement->childNodes->length;
 $dataElement = $dom->createElement("data");
 $dataElement->setAttribute("id", $total);

 $dataElement->appendChild($dom->createElement("a",$_REQUEST['a']));
 $dataElement->appendChild($dom->createElement("b",$_REQUEST['b']));
 $dataElement->appendChild($dom->createElement("id", $total));

 $rootElement->appendChild($dataElement);
 $dom->save("a.xml");

}
?>

<form> 
 <input type="text" name="a" />
 <input type="text" name="b" />
<button type="submit" name="ok" >update</button>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The xml code with preserveWhiteSpace = false;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
  <data id="1">
    <a>dfg shhs</a>
    <b>dhhdhd dhdhd</b>
    <id>1</id>
  </data>
  <data id="1">
    <a>dggd mdmmd</a>
    <b>dhhd dndh</b>
    <id>1</id>
  </data>
  <data id="2">
    <a>dggd mdmmd</a>
    <b>dhhd dndh</b>
    <id>2</id>
  </data>
</document>
```

The xml code with preserveWhiteSpace = true;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>

<data id="1"><a>dggd mdmmd</a><b>dhhd dndh</b><id>1</id></data><data id="2"><a>dggd mdmmd</a><b>dhhd dndh</b><id>2</id></data><data id="3"><a>dggd mdmmd</a><b>dhhd dndh</b><id>3</id></data></document>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of thing I've changed, some are more niceties, some are the cause of the problem.  I've added comments to the code rather than explain some points...

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","utf-8");
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->load("a.xml");

    // Fetch the document root element
    $rootElement = $dom->documentElement;
    // Set total to the number of <data> elements (add 1 for next)
    $total = $dom->getElementsByTagName("data")->length + 1;
    $dataElement = $dom->createElement("data");
    $dataElement->setAttribute("id", $total);

    $dataElement->appendChild($dom->createElement("a",$_REQUEST['a']));
    $dataElement->appendChild($dom->createElement("b",$_REQUEST['b']));
    $dataElement->appendChild($dom->createElement("id", $total));

    $rootElement->appendChild($dataElement);
    if ( $total == 1 )  {
        $tmp = $dom->saveXML();
        $dom->loadXML($tmp);
    }
    $dom->save("a.xml");

}
?>

<form>
 <input type="text" name="a" />
 <input type="text" name="b" />
<button type="submit" name="ok" >update</button>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem you were having is that you were simply looking at the number of children of the root element.  As DOM is very specific, even the whitespace you were trying to preserve is classed as an element.  So this is potentially a very misleading way of trying to count the items in a document. This is why I've changed it to count the number of `<data>` elements instead.

The last thing I've done is that as you may notice, when you add the first item and save it, the format isn't how you'd expect.  This is why just before the save the code unloads and reloads the XML (around where I have `if ( $total == 1 )  {`, which will force the code to reformat the XML the first time round only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I change getElementsByTagName("data") to getElementsByTagName("document") then I have the same problem, or a different problem, the id tag shows only the number 2

Comment: I have tried to put manually <document> tags and leave the data on the php file. This way is all ok for the id number. Thanks